# Error in formula.py in xlwt3 python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.3, xlwt

I'm trying to write in a xls or xlsx, trying to use the xlwt3 but it gives me the following error message when import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tcp/Documents/Python/Working/Menu.py", line 6, in <module>
import xlwt3
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/xlwt3/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .workbook import Workbook
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/xlwt3/workbook.py", line 5, in <module>
from .worksheet import Worksheet
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/xlwt3/worksheet.py", line 7, in <module>
from .row import Row
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/xlwt3/row.py", line 8, in <module>
from . import formula
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/xlwt3/formula.py", line 6, in <module>
class Formula(object):
ValueError: '__init__' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

Is there a solution or any other tool?

Using in MacOS and xlwt3-0.1.2

Comment: I see that the devs have abandoned that project: *I doubt that there will ever be a stable version of xlwt3.* and *DEVELOPMENT STOPPED - 03.01.2011*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` should not be listed in the `__slots__` attribute of the class; slots cannot refer to methods as each slot is implemented by a descriptor object instead.

There is a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/mozman/xlwt3/pull-request/1/fix-slots-for-python-33-compatability/diff) in the project repository that fixes that specific problem. It simply removes the `"__init__"` string from the `__slots__` definition.

Do note that the authors of the package have abandoned the project:

> **DEVELOPMENT STOPPED** - 03.01.2011
>
> I doubt that there will ever be a stable version of xlwt3.

Comment: I made the change in it Works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to write in a xls or xlsx

As an alternative, the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org) module works with Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Great! Did you know if XlsxWriter could write an existing xlsx or xls?

Comment: No it can only create a new xlsx file.

Comment: Thanks, i will use this module

Answer (score 0):

Try package [xlwt-future](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt-future) for writing xls files in Python 3.x